# includeHTML требует особый режим для запуска браузера

Tags: javascript, spa

Всем привет. Для имитации SPA решил попробовать includeHTML, который часто тут упоминали. Скачал, но при попытке запустить пример или даже прописав у себя нужные тэги - каждый раз получаю одно и то же окно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То, что требуется, я для ярлыка прописал, но ничего не изменилось(пробовал с другим браузером и то же самое).
Может он уже устарел и не поддерживается современными браузерами?

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось просто: для этого случая свой сайт нужно либо залить на локальный сервер, либо на хостинг и все будет работать без ошибок.